# "No module named pygame.base" - pygame e pypy

Tags: linux, python-3.x, packages, pygame

depois de diversas tentativas e erros, eu consegui instalar o pygame 1.9.2a0 no pypy3, baixando a versão atual via mercurial e instalando via /caminho/pypy3 setup.py

Porém na hora de dar import, me aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafael/PycharmProjects/pygame-teste/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/opt/pypy3-2.4.0-linux64/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named pygame.base
```

Esso erro também acontecia com frequência antes no python3, (quando eu usava Debian Wheezy), mas funcionava de boas no PyCharm. Agora que estou usando o Jessie e o pygame funciona perfeitamente no python3, esse erro aparece pro pypy (e nem o Pycharm faz funcionar)

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: negativo, acabei desistindo do pypy

Answer (score 0):

Instala pygame via PIP.

Se estiver usando algum sistema operacional do estilo UNIX/GNU/Linux você consegue instalar pygame via PIP:

1) Instalação PIP

A) Se não tiver PIP instalado:

**sudo apt install python-pip**

B) Tambem da para instala ele em windows... é so fazer download deste arquivo:

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Ir ate a pasta onde foi salvo o arquivo e executar uma consola de comandos:

**`python get-pip.py`**

2) finalmente executar:

```
pip install pygame
```